# Python get last reading time of a file

Tags: python, time, file-access

I'm looking for a solution to get the time a file was read at last. The file will be not modified or created just opened in reading mode. This works but only for writing in a file. If I open the file in read mode, the time is not correct:

```
f = open('my_path/test.txt', 'r')
f.close()

print time.ctime(os.stat('my_path/test.txt').st_mtime)
```

Any hints?

Comment: I tried this and it does not work if I open the file in read mode inside Python code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are looking at the wrong entry in the `stat` structure. You want to use the `.st_atime` value instead:

```
print time.ctime(os.stat('my_path/test.txt').st_atime)
```

From the [`os.stat()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat):

> - `st_atime` - time of most recent access,

Note that not all systems update the `atime` timestamp, see [Criticism of atime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_%28system_call%29#Criticism_of_atime). As of 2.6.30, Linux kernels by default use the `relatime` setting, where `atime` values are only updated if over 24 hours old. You can alter this by setting the `strictatime` option in `fstab`.

Windows Vista also disabled updates to `atime`, but you can [re-enable them](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/microsoft/enable-last-access-time-stamp-to-files-folder-windows-7/).

Comment: This works only if I open the file in the explorer but not in the Python code...

Comment: In that case the OS is only updating the access time under certain circumstances that Python doesn't trigger. If the `atime` value is not updated, there is no other metric that shows you when a file was last accessed. What platform is this, Windows?

Comment: No, Linux (Ubuntu 12.04) but the program must run cross platform. Up to now I solved this by saving the file name into a new file but I found it not so nice. Maybe this is the only way...

Comment: @snowflake: see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_%28system_call%29#Criticism_of_atime), you are running a Linux system with `relatime` enabled. `atime` is only updated once every 24 hours in that case.

Comment: Mmmm, thanks  Martijn.

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer. This worked on my personal PC, however I don't want to change those settings from users of my software, so I will stay with saving the file name into another file. Good to know!