# How to fix the logic of date reading?

Tags: python, datetime, time

I currently have a statement that says:

```
import glob
push_directory = 'Risk_Summary'

current_dir = os.getcwd() + '/Reports/' + push_directory + '/Saved_PDF/*'
list_of_files = glob.glob(current_dir)
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
file_name = os.path.basename(latest_file)
date_created = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getctime(latest_file))

if date_created.day == datetime.now().day:
    risk_summary_report(latest_file, file_name, push_directory)
else:
    pass
```

The problem with using date created is the fact that it relies on the time someone created the file.

Here I have 2 options

- Accept a range of dates
- Figure how to get 'date accessed' which would result in the day it was saved.

How can I change my logic to either accept a week range of dates, or (preferably) how can I get the date of access?

---

I found this link: [Python get last reading time of a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16464228/python-get-last-reading-time-of-a-file)

Having trouble figuring out how to implement it in my code. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the last accessed time by `os.path.getatime()`.

From [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#module-os.path):

> `os.path.getatime(path)` 
> Return the time of last access of path. The return value is a number giving the number of seconds since the epoch (see the `time` module). Raise `OSError` if the file does not exist or is inaccessible.

#### Sample Usage

```
os.path.getatime('./test.txt')
```

Output

```
1503332001.0
```